# How to manage resources (Image, font, color) in an Eclipse plug-in project?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

My Eclipse plug-in project has some images and uses some fonts. So I created a singleton class named `ImageManager` to manage images, which can make the image object to be a single one in the whole project.

But it is not perfect, and I can't dispose of the image at the right time. So, I need a better mechanism to manage these resources, including images, fonts, colors, etc.

Comment: Look at the JFace `ImageRegistry`, `FontRegistry`, `ColorRegistry`, ... classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JFace offers the `ResourceManager` class to help with creating and disposing of images, fonts, and colors.

For each resource type, there is also a corresponding resource descriptor: `ImageDescriptor`, `FontDescriptor`, `ColorDescriptor`. Resource descriptors are lightweight objects that reference an image/font/color without occupying an operation system resource.

Resource descriptors are able to create actual resources, for example:

```java
ImageDescriptor imageDescriptor = ImageDescriptor.createFromURL( "..." );
Image image = imageDescriptor.createImage();
```

A `ResourceManager` is able to create and buffer resources from resource descriptors and free all resources that it created directly when disposed of.

A specialized resource manager, the `LocalResourceManager`, can be attached to an SWT control and will be disposd of when the control is disposed of.

Resource managers can also be nested so that child resource managers can re-use resources that were previously allocated by one of their parent resource managers.

If your plug-in has a plug-in activator that extends `AbstractUIPlugin`, you already have an image registry accessible through `AbstractUIPlugin::getImageRegistry()`. Override the `initializeImageRegistry()` method to fill the registry. Avoid using `ImageRegistry::get()` because this method allocates an image that cannot be freed and will stay during the entire life-time of your plug-in.

Most workbench APIs use resource descriptors, e.g. `Action::setImageDescriptor()` or `IEditorInput::getImageDescriptor()`. If application code uses resources, follow this practice and prefer to use resource descriptors over actual resources. Create resources only when needed and dispose of them as soon as they aren't needed any more.

This article contains some general rules when using SWT resources: https://www.eclipse.org/articles/swt-design-2/swt-design-2.html